# Apply function with three attributes in R

Tags: r

I have a table with three columns `ABC`, `EFG`, `HIJ`. I would like to create a fourth column `KLM` which is a function of the conditional value of ABC, and a operation result on `EFG` and `HIJ`.

For now I am using a loop that takes about 15 minutes over 400,000 rows. And that does not seem very R to me. There must be a way to do this significantly less time:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
  if(is.na(df$ABC[i]) == FALSE ){
    df$KLM[i] <- as.numeric(df$EFG[i] * df$HIJ[i])
  } else {
    df$KLM[i] = NaN
  }
}
```

I have added the df:

```
ABC = c("NaN", 232,234,233,232.5)
EFG = c(12,12,12,12,12)
HIJ = c(10.75, 10.95, 11.25, 10.85, 10.55)
KLM = c(0,0,0,0,0)

df <- as.data.frame(cbind(ABC, EFG, HIJ, KLM))
df < unfactor(df)


> df
    ABC EFG   HIJ KLM
1   NaN  12 10.75   0
2   232  12 10.95   0
3   234  12 11.25   0
4   233  12 10.85   0
5 232.5  12 10.55   0
```

Does anyone knows how to simplify and make more efficient please ?

Comment: Please show your current table result and the script you used to create the tables.

Comment: `df$KLM <- ifelse(!is.na(df$ABC), df$EFG * df$HIJ, NaN)`

Comment: Are you sure: `ABC = c("NaN", 232,234,233,232.5)` and not `ABC = c(NaN, 232,234,233,232.5)` ?

Comment: @jogo your solution is actually the one I was looking for. Used it 5 years ago and totally forgot. Thank you ! I thought I could get there with applys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@jogo's solution mentioned in the comments is the best vectorized solution for data.frame.

Using `data.table` it can be optimized as follows:

```
dt = as.data.table(df)
dt[,`:=`(KLM=NaN)]
set(x = dt, i =which(!is.na(dt$ABC)),j="KLM",value = as.numeric(EFG * HIJ))
```